# Can someone see what's wrong with my code (ARRAY rotations)?

Tags: python, arrays, rotation

I'm sure the mistake is in the rotate function but I can't find what it is.
code is in python3

```
def rotate(arr, n):
    x = arr[n - 1]
    b = list()
    b.append(x)
    for i in range(0,len(arr) - 1):
        b.append(arr[i]);

    arr = b

a = [1,3,4,5,5,7,8,9]


print('array before is: ',a)
n=len(a)
rotate(a, n)




print('array after rotation: ',a)
```

Edit: I just want to know whats wrong with the existing code. Please don't give an alternate solution.

Comment: `arr = b` will not set the `a` variable, since `arr` is a local variable, that is a reference. Note that Python does *not* perform a *call-by-reference*, but a *call-by-value*.

Comment: Expected output is [9,1,3,4,5,5,7,8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one issue is here:

> arr = b

You are assigning to a local variable here. That will have no effect.
Replace that with `return b`
And use like so:

```
print('array after rotation: ', rotate(a,n))
```

Possibly more issues, but this is the first thing that hits the eye.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rotate(arr, n):
    return arr[n:] + arr[:n]
```

To get `[9, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8]` from `a = [1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9]`,

you need to do `rotate(a, len(a) - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
def rotate(arr, n):
    # ...
    arr = b
```

does not do much. `arr` is a local variable, so setting it to a different value has no effect on the variable with which you called that. Python does not perform *call-by-reference*, it does *call-by-value*. If the object is mutable, you can change the state of that object, but you can not change the reference of the variable pointing to that object (or at least not without some tricks).

The most elegant way to solve this is probably to *return* the new object, and set it at the caller level:

```
def rotate(arr, n):
    return arr[n:] + arr[:n]
```

and make a call like:

```
arr = rotate(arr, len(n)-1)
```